# Constructing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to submit a Collection (set, list, array) with objects that consists of:

`id, phoneNumber, phoneType`

I have a bunch of divs, here's some example HTML:

```
<div id="f9" class="facilityBox">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label>BRANCH</label>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;"> <a href="#" onclick="return Location.submitUpdateFacility(9)'">Save changes</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="phoneSet">
        <input type="text" value="787-788-1111" class="phones" name="number" />
        <select class="phoneType" name="type">
            <option selected="selected" value="PHONE">Phone</option>
            <option value="FAX">Fax</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="6" class="phoneId" name="id" />
    </div>
    <div class="phoneSet">
        <input type="text" value="787-795-4095" class="phones" name="number" />
        <select class="phoneType" name="type">
            <option value="PHONE">Phone</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="FAX">Fax</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="106" class="phoneId" name="id" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This div's id will be `f+identifier`, so for now it's `f9`

the js I have so far is:

```
Location.submitUpdateFacility = function (facilityId) {
    $("#updateFacility input[name=index]").val(facilityId);
    var id = facilityId;
    var phones;
    $("#" + id + " .phoneSet").each(function () {
        phones += {
            id: $(".phoneId input[name=id]").val(),
            phoneNumber: $(".phones input[name=number]").val(),
            phoneType: $(".phoneType select[name=type]").selected().val()
        };
    });    
};
```

My problem is upon Firebug/Chrome console debugging, it does not go into the loop and thus no array is ever created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `.each(function (index, element) {});`?

Comment: Don't use IDs starting with numbers.

Comment: Considering it should iterate over `#f9 .phoneSet` which should be every div with class phoneSet under div with id f9, I'm not convinced this would make any difference. Furthermore I have no need for the index anywhere, so yea. I'm not particularly sure what element does though.

Comment: Now things are a bit more clear to me. :)

Comment: @MelanciaUK: So, in HTML5 you're now allowed to have IDs starting with numbers. Still a bad idea from a compatibility standpoint, but it is allowed.

Comment: @ColinDeClue I wasn't aware of that. What a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that you are passing "9" in as the function parameter that is then being converted to a jquery selector as `"#" + id + " .phoneSet"`. This is generating `"#9 .phoneSet"` which is incorrect.

You should be using `"#f" + id + " .phoneSet"`.

It should also be noted that the other selectors that you use (eg ".phoneId input[name=id]") may also need correcting before this works fully as you expect.

Comment: it seems I did miss that f... christ, and to think i've been at this for at least 2 hours.

Comment: @Nimchip: Its what I call "Code blindness". You've been looking at the code long enough that you *knew* that the f was there so you didn't actually look closely at the code to ensure that it actually was. :)